# Plaintext not being printed when ciphertext deciphered

Tags: python

When I give an option to decrypt, it is not displaying the deciphered text once code runs. The code works fine until this point. The users message is successfully encrypted and all of the printed questions and replies seem to work, it is just the fact that the deciphered message isn't printed, it just moves onto the next question. I would like to know how to solve this problem.

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
L = len(alphabet)
Question1 = input('Hello, please insert your message: ')
key1 = input('Please insert the key you would like to use (Please keep it between 1 and 26): ')
cipher = ''

# Encrytping the message

for A in Question1:
    if A in alphabet:
        cipher +=  alphabet[(alphabet.index(A)+key1)%L]
print(cipher)

#Decrytping the message


Question2 = input('Would you like to decrypt this message?: ')
cipher2 = ''
if input == 'Yes, yes, y, Y, yeah, Yeah':
    key2 = key1
    for A in Question2:
        if A in alphabet:
            cipher2 +=  alphabet[(alphabet.index(A)-key2)%L]
    print(cipher2)
else:
    Question3 = input('Would you like to encrypt another message?: ')
    if input == 'Yes, yes, y, Y, yeah, Yeah':
        start()
    else:
        print ('Thank you for your time young Sir/Madam')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where to begin. Well first off, I assume you are using Python 3.x, right?.. and I assume you are new to Python?

Next, let's assume in the second part the user is inputting a response that matches the possibles cases (Yes, Y, etc). Try using "Question.upper()" if that's your only method of getting an answer from the user.

Then, you aren't using the correct variable when using the if statement. you are asking if the function is equal to "yes" (input=='yesYesetc') whe you should do """if Question2 in "YesYyes, etc" """

Finally, you are trying to decrypt that variable "Question2" when you are in the loop "for A in Question2:" when it should be "for A in cipher:"

I haven't tested this, but let me know if I'm in the ball park ;)